# How to join Candidate with requisition in Taleo Connect Client?

Tags: xml, join, taleo, taleo-connect-client

I need to query submissions by Candidates to a Specific Requisition using Taleo Connect Client.
I have the requisition id and candidate id.
I wrote the simple requisition export as:

```
<soapenv:Envelope
        xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <find:findPartialEntities
                xmlns:find="<URL>" >
            <find:mappingVersion><URL></find:mappingVersion>
            <find:query>
                <quer:query
                        xmlns:quer="http://itk.taleo.com/ws/query"
                        alias="Source"
                        projectedClass="SourcingRequest"
                        locale="en">
                    <quer:projections>
                        <quer:projection>
                            <quer:field path="Requisition,HotJob"/>
                        </quer:projection>
                        <quer:projection>
                            <quer:field path="Requisition,ContestNumber"/>
                        </quer:projection>
                        <quer:projection>
                            <quer:field path="Requisition,State,Description"/>
                        </quer:projection>
                                        </quer:projections>
                                        <quer:filterings>
                        <quer:filtering>
                            <quer:equal>
                                <quer:field path="Requisition,Number"/>
                                <quer:string>xxxxxx</quer:string>
                            </quer:equal>
                        </quer:filtering>
                                        </quer:filterings>
                                        <quer:sortings>
                        <quer:sorting ascending="false">
                            <quer:field path="OpenDate"/>
                        </quer:sorting>
                        <quer:sorting ascending="true">
                            <quer:field path="Requisition,JobInformation,Title"/>
                        </quer:sorting>
                        <quer:sorting ascending="true">
                            <quer:field path="Requisition,JobInformation,Organization,Name"/>
                        </quer:sorting>
                    </quer:sortings>
                </quer:query>
            </find:query>
            <find:attributes>
                <find:entry>
                    <find:key>pagingsize</find:key>
                    <find:value>200</find:value>
                </find:entry>
                <find:entry>
                    <find:key>pageindex</find:key>
                    <find:value>1</find:value>
                </find:entry>
            </find:attributes>
        </find:findPartialEntities>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I found that Candidate and Requisition are separate entity, so I was trying to join Candidate with Requisition with quer:joinings like:

```
<quer:joinings>
  <quer:joining>
    <quer:field path="Candidate"/>
  </quer:joining>
</quer:joinings>
```

But it's throwing error.

How do I fetch Requisitions and Candidates applied for the requisition using Taleo Connect Client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use Application Entity

```
    <quer:query projectedClass="Application">
  <quer:subQueries/>
  <quer:projections>
    <quer:projection>
      <quer:field path="Candidate,FirstName"/>
    </quer:projection>
    <quer:projection>
      <quer:field path="Requisition,ContestNumber"/>
    </quer:projection>
  </quer:projections>
  <quer:projectionFilterings/>
  <quer:filterings>
    <quer:filtering>
      <quer:equal>
        <quer:field path="Requisition,ContestNumber"/>
        <quer:string>0141806</quer:string>
      </quer:equal>
    </quer:filtering>
  </quer:filterings>
  <quer:sortings/>
  <quer:sortingFilterings/>
  <quer:groupings/>
  <quer:joinings/>
</quer:query>
```